# View data of .mdf file within visual studio

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a simple problem but have searched all across google and SO to no avail.

I have a `.mdf` file that has 3 tables, I am working with this file in ASP.NET WebForms e.g updating, adding data etc... I want to be able to view the contents of the `.mdf` file in Visual Studio to make sure that the queries (written in C#) are working correctly.

At the moment I am doing this by opening the file in SQL Server 2014 but that way I have to close visual studio as the file can only be used on instance.

I know this can be achieved by connecting to a server but this is and `.mdf` file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think there is no way currently, because when you open the .mdf file it lock by that software such as VS or MSS.

Answer (score 4):

Go to **View > SQL Server Object Explorer** right click the `SQL Server node` and select `Add SQL server`.

But be aware. If you are developing a program that uses this connection to, then the application might throw an exception saying that you can connect to the database only once.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty solution with empty project in visual studio.
2. Add a mdf file to project(Right click on project--> Add Existing Items)
3. Now double click on mdf file which will open server explorer/database explorer.
4. Then expand db to see table, views .. etc...

Comment: Thank you...!  (more characters to fill min. length)